# Open fragment from activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I wanna open fragment from my activity. The problem is that the fragment never appears.
This is the part of my activity:

```
 btn_opciones.setOnValueChangedListener(new ToggleButton.OnValueChangedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onValueChanged(int position) {
        if(position == 1){
            OrdenarComplejosFragment ordenarComplejosFragment = new OrdenarComplejosFragment();
            FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();

            ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
            ft.add(ordenarComplejosFragment, null);
            ft.commit();
        }

    }
});
```

And this is my fragment that I wanna open and show:

```
public class OrdenarComplejosFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_ordenar_complejos, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        //do your stuff for your fragment here
    }
}
```

The xml of the fragment above:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="HOLAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA"
        android:id="@+id/textView35"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I don't know why the fragment never show. The button works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a different "add" method.  Using the one which takes in a view id indicates where the fragment should show up within the existing Activity's layout.

```
ft.add(R.id.fragment_frame, ordenarComplejosFragment);
```

Fragments are always housed within an Activity.  If your activity doesn't provide a container/location for the fragment to show up, you'll need to re-think the layout or consider opening this new view with a separate Activity.

Comment: R.id.fragment_frame is the id of a <fragment> into activity_main.xml.? The  problem is that i want to show the fragment only on click. No always

Comment: R.id.fragment_frame is the id of a container view (e.g. RelativeLayout).  Let's get one thing working at a time.  Does this code get the fragment visible on the screen?

Comment: "No view found for id 0x7f0e0167 "  The problem is that I don't know witch id I have to put ft.add(R.id.container_fragment_ordenar_complejos, ordenarComplejosFragment); I put the id of the relative layout of the fragment xml. I mean I don't know how to provide a conotainer/location in my activity, sorry for that, please let me a example

Comment: Put the id of the relative layout of your activity_main.xml - it would probably be beneficial to add the contents of your activity_main.xml to your original question.

Comment: How can the fragment contain the half of the screen?

Comment: I'm not following this second question...  Maybe a separate SO question is in order.